# Excel 2016 - Mac - Automatically Update All Excel Files By Changing a Cell Value When Files Are Closed

Tags: excel

I have multiple Excel files which are connected together. Files are saved in different folders. Once I change a cell value, all the files get updated when they are open, but when they are closed, they dont update. Is there a way to get all files updated if they are closed also?

Comment: Can you explain how the files update, is a macro running?

Comment: @user3240704, no it is not. the files update when they are open in Excel, shall I user Macron to automatically update them?

Comment: How are the files "connected"? Are you looking for help to improve the current process or expecting others to come up with a solution? Show what you've done. With 700+ points, you know how SO works

Comment: @user3240704, the `E2` cell in a workbook is called by `'/Users/akwasiah/Documents/forms/4-working/5-jackson-excel-sheets/rows/[Jackson-00001.xls]Jackson W11'!E2`, I really do not have any other information :), cheers

Comment: OK, so the files update because they hard-coded to reference the specific worksheet & cell. They only update when they are active (and trying to action their hard-coded reference). If you wish to update these cells when the files are closed you'll need to move the process of data transfer outside the Excel files. I like [Powershell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/) but you may have your favorite language to build this process

Comment: @user3240704, awesome, thanks for your help.